# MYSQL load data

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, load-data-infile

```
'mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'students.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE students
    -> FIELD TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';`
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELD TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'' at line 3.

I'm not sure where my error is occuring. Can someone help me? :(

Comment: the single quotes used at the beginning and end of the code was not used in my code but I had to put it there to upload this question

Comment: It's `FIELDS`, not `FIELD`. See the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html